# SQL rounding varchar when used in a function

Tags: sql-server, function

When I have a query such as :

```
SELECT top 1 LabResult_Result as Value
FROM [TopsData].[dbo].[VIEW_PatientLabResult]
where MasterLabCode_ID = '000000003H'
  and Patient_ID = 'ZZZZZ00063'
  and LabResult_RecordState = 0
  and datediff(d,'11/19/2013',LabResult_DateTimeOfObservation) >= 0 
ORDER BY LabResult_DateTimeOfObservation
```

the result is nice, usually a varchar that resembles a decimale such as `1.10`

However, if I wrap this in a function, it returns just a `1`:

```
declare @R varchar(10)

SELECT @R = Value FROM (
    SELECT top 1 LabResult_Result as Value
    FROM [TopsData].[dbo].[VIEW_PatientLabResult]
    where MasterLabCode_ID = '000000003H'
      and Patient_ID = 'ZZZZZ00063'
      and LabResult_RecordState = 0
      and datediff(d,'11/19/2013',LabResult_DateTimeOfObservation) >= 0 
    ORDER BY LabResult_DateTimeOfObservation
    )q


return @R
END
```

Obviously I have plans to make it generic with parameters,etc.. But if the hardcoded query wont return the correct varchar, I do not know what to do.

Comment: What is the actual data type of your LabResult_Result column?

Comment: From the source table: varchar(250)

Comment: Off the top of my head, I don't know what would cause the behavior you are reporting.  However, if you want a decimal, then store it as a decimal!  Also, I don't see any need for your proc, it isn't doing anything a simple query can't do.

Comment: I can't store a decimal, many results are not decimals.  I would like the varchar to be returned unchanged.  This is merely one step in a much more complicated query as a proc is definitely preferred.

Comment: can you post the complete code of the function that is giving you fits?  There may be something missing in the header which is affecting your results.

Comment: If my answer helped, it would be useful to post the full function definition instead of just the body, then people can learn from exactly where you went wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bet your functions says:

```
RETURNS VARCHAR
```

Or:

```
@input VARCHAR
```

Instead of:

```
RETURNS VARCHAR(10)
```

Or:

```
@input VARCHAR(10)
```

Full repro... both of these function calls return `a`:

```
USE tempdb;
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.foo1
(
  @a VARCHAR(10)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR
----- LAZY! ---^^^^ Missing length specification!
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN @a;
END
GO

SELECT dbo.foo1('abcdefghij');
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.foo2
(
  @a VARCHAR
  ---- LAZY! ^^^^ Missing length specification
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN @a;
END
GO

SELECT dbo.foo2('abcdefghij');
GO

DROP FUNCTION dbo.foo1, dbo.foo2;
GO
```

Always, always, always specify a length when declaring or defining variable-width types in any context. In some cases SQL Server will assume you meant 1, in some cases 30, in very few cases is either guess correct. More info here:

- [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)